# How to pass mysql table as an array to be used in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, import

I'm doing a simple javascript application. It involves several items in different tables stored using MYSQL.

The user has to choose an item from a table. Based on his choice he can choose a second item from another table, then a third item from a third table based on his former choices, and continues on the same pattern.

I just have one simple problem that I don't know a simple method to import tables from MYSQL into javascript arrays!!

Any ideas of how to do that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the easiest way to send MySQL data to Javascript using PHP is as a JSON object using jQuery.

In PHP: connect to your db, do your query.
Assuming you store your results in an array called $results, just do:

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

This will format the output as a JSON object.

This is the javascript side (using jquery) - note the GET var I'm passing as an example, in case you need that for the tablename or id or whatever:

```
$.getJSON( 'json.php', { some_get_var: 1 }, function(data){
    var i, total = data.length;
    for ( i = 0; i < total; ++i ) {
        // do whatever with your data, like populate a select.
        // your data would be like:
        // data[i].fieldname
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode($arr)
```

The array you want to return, wrap it in the `json_encode` method. If you are using jQuery it will automatically convert it to an object in the success handler

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access your database from Javascript. You'll have to use PHP to render the JS code necessary for loading those arrays.

For that, you can use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) function. You could also do it by ajax, that way, you can separate your php code from your JavaScript code and keep it organized.